# Append to sed output

Tags: unix, sed, grep, append, output

***UNIX***

I want to append to my sed output. For example the output is:

"/dir1/dir2/file"

I want to output "/dir1/dir 2/file is missing"

I have:

diff -rq $1 $2 | grep "^Only in *" | sed -e 's/Only in //g' -e 's,: ,/,g' -e 's/*/* is missing/g'

which outputs "/dir1/dir2/file" and not "/dir1/dir2/file is missing."

Comment: If you want to add 'is missing' to the end of the output, you should use `s/$/ is missing/`.  I cannot understand what `s//* is missing/g'` is supposed to do.  It certainly won't do what you hope.

Comment: I have no idea what I was doing, I am very new to unix, Ill try what you've suggested, thanks!